# Generic UDAF in Spark 3.0 using Aggregator

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, aggregator

Spark 3.0 has deprecated `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` and I was trying to rewrite my udaf using `Aggregator`. Basic usage of `Aggregator` is simple, however, I struggle with more generic version of the function.

I will try to explain my problem with this example, an implementation of `collect_set`. It's not my actual case, but it's easier to explain the problem:

```scala
class CollectSetDemoAgg(name: String) extends Aggregator[Row, Set[Int], Set[Int]] {
  override def zero = Set.empty
  override def reduce(b: Set[Int], a: Row) = b + a.getInt(a.fieldIndex(name))
  override def merge(b1: Set[Int], b2: Set[Int]) = b1 ++ b2
  override def finish(reduction: Set[Int]) = reduction
  override def bufferEncoder = Encoders.kryo[Set[Int]]
  override def outputEncoder = ExpressionEncoder()
}

// using it:
df.agg(new CollectSetDemoAgg("rank").toColumn as "result").show()
```

I prefer `.toColumn` vs `.udf.register`, but it's not the point here.

**Problem:**
I can not make universal version of this Aggregator, it will only work with integers.

I've attempted:

```scala
class CollectSetDemo(name: String) extends Aggregator[Row, Set[Any], Set[Any]]
```

It crashes with error:

```
No Encoder found for Any
- array element class: "java.lang.Object"
- root class: "scala.collection.immutable.Set"
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for Any
- array element class: "java.lang.Object"
- root class: "scala.collection.immutable.Set"
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.$anonfun$serializerFor$1(ScalaReflection.scala:567)
```

I could not go with `CollectSetDemo[T]`, case I was not able to proper `outputEncoder`. Also, when using udaf, I can only work with Spark data types, columns, etc.

Comment: Hi, why do you prefer .toColumn vs .udf.register?

Answer (score 1):

Have not found a nice way to solve the situation, but I was able to somewhat workaround it. Code was partially borrowed from `RowEncoder`:

```scala
class CollectSetDemoAgg(name: String, fieldType: DataType) extends Aggregator[Row, Set[Any], Any] {
  override def zero = Set.empty
  override def reduce(b: Set[Any], a: Row) = b + a.get(a.fieldIndex(name))
  override def merge(b1: Set[Any], b2: Set[Any]) = b1 ++ b2
  override def finish(reduction: Set[Any]) = reduction.toSeq
  override def bufferEncoder = Encoders.kryo[Set[Any]]

  // now
  override def outputEncoder = {
    val mirror = ScalaReflection.mirror
    val tt = fieldType match {
      case ArrayType(LongType, _) => typeTag[Seq[Long]]
      case ArrayType(IntegerType, _) => typeTag[Seq[Int]]
      case ArrayType(StringType, _) => typeTag[Seq[String]]
      // .. etc etc
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Could not create encoder for ${name} column (${fieldType})")
    }
    val tpe = tt.in(mirror).tpe

    val cls = mirror.runtimeClass(tpe)
    val serializer = ScalaReflection.serializerForType(tpe)
    val deserializer = ScalaReflection.deserializerForType(tpe)

    new ExpressionEncoder[Any](serializer, deserializer, ClassTag[Any](cls))
  }
}
```

One thing, that I had to add was result data type parameter in aggregator. The usage then changed to:

```scala
df.agg(new CollectSetDemoAgg("rank", new ArrayType(IntegerType, true)).toColumn as "result").show()
```

I really don't like how it turned out, but it works. I also welcome any suggestions how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Modification of [@Ramunas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8389012/ramunas) answer with generics:

```
class CollectSetDemoAgg[T: TypeTag](name: String) extends Aggregator[Row, Set[T], Seq[T]] {
  override def zero = Set.empty
  override def reduce(b: Set[T], a: Row) = b + a.getAs[T](a.fieldIndex(name))
  override def merge(b1: Set[T], b2: Set[T]) = b1 ++ b2
  override def finish(reduction: Set[T]) = reduction.toSeq
  override def bufferEncoder = Encoders.kryo[Set[T]]
  
  override def outputEncoder = {
    val tt = typeTag[Seq[T]]
    val tpe = tt.in(mirror).tpe

    val cls = mirror.runtimeClass(tpe)
    val serializer = serializerForType(tpe)
    val deserializer = deserializerForType(tpe)

    new ExpressionEncoder[Seq[T]](serializer, deserializer, ClassTag[Seq[T]](cls))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache [DataFu-Spark](https://github.com/apache/datafu/tree/main/datafu-spark) has an example of this in its [MultiArraySet](https://github.com/apache/datafu/blob/main/datafu-spark/src/main/scala/datafu/spark/Aggregators.scala#L76) UDAF. (disclosure: I am a member of DataFu and wrote this code).

The declaration looks like this:

```
/**
 * Essentially the same as MultiSet, but gets an Array for input.
 * There is an extra option to limit the number of keys (like @CountDistinctUpTo)
 */
  class MultiArraySet[IN: Ordering : TypeTag](maxKeys: Int = -1)(implicit t: ClassTag[IN]) extends Aggregator[Array[IN], Map[IN, Int], Map[IN, Int]] with Serializable {
```

Unlike @Greg's answer, I used kryo encoding for the generic *IN* type.

```
implicit val inEncoder: Encoder[IN] = Encoders.kryo[IN]

def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Map[IN, Int]] = implicitly[Encoder[Map[IN, Int]]]

def outputEncoder: Encoder[Map[IN, Int]] = implicitly[Encoder[Map[IN, Int]]]
```